# Can vowels be combined in English without forming diphthongs?

Tags: phonology, vowels, diphthongs, phonotactics

Usually all combinations of vowels in English function as diphthongs. Are there any combinations of vowels in English that do not function as diphthongs? if there are no such examples - I would be grateful to you if you mention the source, where this restriction is mentioned as a combinatory rule for English vowel phonemes.

> You are absolutely right -my question didn't sound precise. I meant
>   the phonotactics of Old English - were there any cases of vowel
>   combinations within one morpheme that were not diphthongs? Something
>   like CV+VC or CCV+V

(A later [comment from the original poster](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/52328/can-vowels-be-combined-in-english-without-forming-diphthongs#comment97577_52341))

Comment: Do you mean vowel sounds, or the letters classed as vowels (i.e. a, e, i, o, u and sometimes y)?

Comment: It seems to me that the *definition* of a dipthong is a sequence of two different vowel phonemes. If you mean the letters classed as vowels, there are plenty of counterexamples ("heat", "pour")

Comment: I think you'll need to be clearer about what you are asking for. Vowels in different syllables don't coalesce (eg "rearrange") but they are usually separated by glides rather than glottal stops. But within a syllable what possibilities are there other than a diphthong?

Comment: Very unclear question. _Diphthong_ is a phonetic term, dealing with **spoken** language only. The vagaries of English spelling have nothing to do with diphthongs. It should be clarified or closed.

Comment: Is the American pronunciation of *drawing* what you're looking for? We don't insert the /r/, so it's /drɔ.ɪŋ/ or /drɑ.ɪŋ/ rɑther than /drɔːrɪŋ/. That is, there are two adjacent vowels  with no consonants or semivowels (y,w) between them. I believe that in most British dialects, whenever you have two adjacent vowels, you insert a y or w glide or an r between them.

Comment: @slim - you would usually consider as a diphthong two vowel targets within a single syllable. Whether or not two adjacent vowels are diphthongised or not may be a property of the particular word/morphological circumstances in question, but it can also depend on other factors, e.g. speed of speech or personal ideolect.

Comment: Also, bear in mind that how many syllables a particular (utterance of) a word constitutes isn't a trivial matter.

Answer (score 8):

Examples within a single morpheme exist (e.g., *pIAno,* & *nAIve*), and across morpheme boundaries, it would be very common (e.g., *gOIng*). These are not diphthongs because the two vowels occur in different syllables.

Comment: Thank you for your answers and commments. You are absolutely right -my question didn't sound precise. I meant the phonotactics of Old English - were there any cases of vowel combinations within one morpheme that were not diphthongs? Something like CV+VC or CCV+V

Comment: Is *naïve* with the umlaut ( ¨ ) considered the ideal English spelling, or is it just a vestigial relic that has survived since it entered English from the French language?

Comment: Well, naïve with an umlaut (¨) not, but naïve with a [diaresis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diaeresis_(diacritic)) (¨) probably yes as does name [Zoë](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zoe_(name)). The meaning of this diacritic is precisely to stress, that the two vowels are not diphthongs.

Answer (score 0):

If, as now seems to be the case, the OP is asking about Old English, then Old English *þeod*, meaning ‘people’, was a morpheme, and was quite possibly pronounced as /θeɪɒd/, with a syllable boundary after /eɪ/.

Comment: Who favors a reconstruction as  /θeɪ.ɒd/? That looks very odd to me; a modern English speaker might try to pronounce it that way, but it doesn't look like Old English phonologically. The *ēo* in this word descends from a Proto-Germanic diphthong *eu* (it's cognate to the first part of German "**Deut**sch") so I would think it would be a diphthong in Old English. Wiktionary gives it as /θeːod/.